# Reduce space on bottom of title page

Tags: margins

I want to insert some text at the bottom of my title page, but it always goes to the next page if I put it too low. Can I force the text to stay on the same page, or reducing the margin at the bottom of the page, just for the titlepage?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) that illustrates your problem. That way community members can have something to work with without starting from scratch.

Comment: if you're using the `geometry` package in your document, then you could use `\newgeometry` for the titlepage, and then `\restoregeometry` immediately after it. As Werner says though, a MWE is needed

Comment: Thats what I did now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem, but assuming you want to typeset something at the bottom of a page this can be done with `\vfill`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Text at the top of the page

\vfill

Text at the bottom of the page

\end{document}
```